# QR code based login system [React-native + firebase]

Tags: firebase, react-native, authentication, qr-code

I am newbie dev here. 
I am working on a personal project (React Native + firebase) where the user login flow is something like this:

1. Each app user already has an id card with a unique user id provided to them in the form of a QR code.
2. User scans the QR code in the login page for the app.
3. If the unique id matches with the user id already present in the database - the user is authorized to access the app.

Note there is no sign up in my app.

I have trouble understanding how the implementation flow would look like in firebase. How do I authorize the user in firebase? Is it possible to use the firebase-auth for this?

Currently, I am just manually looking if the unique id exists in the database.     I am allowing the user to navigate from the login page to other pages if the id matches with the id present in the database. Any user can make any changes to the database at present. 
Here is the code I am using at the present:

```
    _login = (status)=> {
    if(status === "success") {
      this.setState ({
        logInStatus: "Login successful!"
      })
      this.props.navigation.navigate("Question")
    }
   else {
     this.setState ({
       logInStatus: "Login failed!"
     })
     this.props.navigation.navigate("Login")
   }
  }

    //check if user exists in the database
      userExists = async (data) => {
        this.setState ({
          logInStatus: "Logging you in!"
        })
        //connect to firebase
        let userRef = firebase.database().ref('/users/')
        let status

        try {
          let value = await userRef.child(data).once('value', function(snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
              status = "success"
            }

          })
        }
        catch(error) {
          this.setState ({
            logInStatus: "Login failed. Try again!"
          })
          console.log("Reached error")
        }

        this._login(status)
      }

    //when user has scanned once
      _handleBarCodeRead = async ({data})=> {
        this.userExists(data)
    //stop user from scanning again
        this.setState ({
          barCodeRead: true,
          fullScreen: false,
        })

      }
```

Clearly this is not a secure way to do the login...what is a better alternative?

This is the database structure which I am using as of now:

```
{
  "schools": {
    "school_001":{
      "name": <name>,
      "id": <school_id>,
      .....other properties unique to the school
    },
    "school_002": {},
    "school_003": {},
    .....
    "school_N": {}
  },

  "groups":{
    "group_001":{
      "group_id": <group ID>,
      "school_id": <school ID>,
      "members":[array list of group memebers/users]
      ....other group properties unique to the group
    },
    "group_002":{},
    .....
    "group_N":{}
  },

  "users":{
    "user_001":{
      "user_id":<user ID>,
      "group_id":<group ID>,
      "school_id": <school ID>
      ....other user properties unique to the user
    },
    "user_002":{},
    ....
    "user_N":{}
  },

  "activity_feed":{
    "school_001":{
      "group_001":{
        "activity_001":{
          "actor": <name of the user>,
          "action": <user's action>,
          ....other properties related to the activity

        },
        "activity_002":{},
        ......
      },
      "group_002":{},
      ....
    },
    "school_002":{},
    ......
  }

}
```

I want users to have write access to only their own user properties, particular group properties and group activity feed.

Comment: Welcome to SO. The question is a bit unclear; are you asking how to craft a security rule? If so, rules are directly related by what you want users to access so we would need to know that to answer. If you're asking something else, it's unclear. Can you update your question so we know what you're actually asking? Please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi Jay, I have updated my question. Hope it is more clear now..

Comment: Much better. How are you creating the users in Firebase - through the Firebase console or some other method? How does the QR code get into firebase? Do you have a Firebase structure that stores the QR codes? Give us a bit more info an maybe we can help.

Comment: I have a list of users with their ids in a spreadsheet. An app script pushes the data to the firebase database structure that I have created. I think this is similar to manually creating the users in Firebase?

Comment: as I mentioned, can you please include your firebase structure?

Comment: @Jay Just added the firebase structure which I am using right now. Hope this helps answer my question.

Comment: If you have a script that pushes data to firebase (to the users node), that is totally unrelated to manually creating users. That data is just data and has nothing to do with a user in Firebase. The way you're doing this is very insecure and goes around secure Firebase Authentication, so not recommended. However. If your implementation must be this, how about creating users in the Firebase console and using that uid as your QR code? Again, not recommended but you could then have a generic password for all users but each user would at least have their own UID and you could use Firebase Rules.

Answer (score 0):

You should put this in your firebase security rule

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth !== null",
    ".write": "auth !== null"
  }
}
```

Comment: But how do I authorize the user? There is no sign up in my application. Users just login through a unique ID provided to them.

Comment: Not sure this answer really applies to the question. The OP is asking how to authenticate users via a QR code and all this does is guarantee a user is authenticated to read and write.